# how to add my own encryption algorithm to https header using c++

Tags: c++, encryption, https

I want to use HTTPS in a secure application, but replacing the symmetric encryption algorithm into a self-defined one.

I'm not quite sure how to achieve this goal. Is it possible to replace the relevant library to a self-defined one? For example, using OpenSSL?

To be more specific, in the first stage, I need to do it on windows platform, could anyone tell me how to begin?

Comment: You did not even say what library you are using to make the HTTPS connection in the first place. Also what exactly do you mean when you say "*replacing the symmetric encryption algorithm into a self-defined one.*"? The ciphers used for TLS are specified. You can select between those, but I hope you don't intend to substitute some custom algorithm.

Comment: This is one of those questions where if someone has to ask it, it means that they will not be able to do it, not just yet; not at least without having significantly more experience and domain knowledge under the belt.

Comment: @uneven_mark i want to add self-defined one

Comment: @AhmadTarabeshi Please edit your question to include more details about what you want to do. At least include: 1. What library you are using to make the HTTPS connection and an example of how you are using it right now. 2. A detailed description of what part of the TLS cipher suit you want to replace and with what exactly you want to replace it.

Comment: @AhmadTarabeshi If you actually mean to replace the TLS block cipher with an algorithm that you came up with yourself, then the whole thing is a terrible idea. You need to be a trained cryptographer to be able to come up with a cipher algorithm that works and isn't easily broken and it doesn't seem that you are trained in the field.

Comment: This is a *really* bad idea.

Comment: @AhmadTarabeshi, I assume you want browsers be able to work with your server, right? So you are going to ask Microsoft, Mozilla, Google to add support for your super-strong algorithm, when you are done with implementation? Did I get it right? Or do you make custom server which has nothing to do with HTTP?